# webstart-maven-plugin: where do the $jnlpspec and $j2seVersion template variables come from?

Tags: java, maven, java-web-start

I've got an application which is distributed as a WebStart application. The application has up until now been managed as a regular NetBeans project, and NetBeans has thus been responsible for generating WebStart application files.

However, I've decided that I'd like to use Maven for this project now. Thus, I will also be using Maven to generate the WebStart application files. More specifically, I'll be using the 'webstart-maven-plugin' to take care of this.

However, there is a couple of variables in the [default 'webstart-maven-plugin' JNLP template](http://mojo.codehaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/examples/default-jnlp-template.vm) which I can't figure out. These variables are $jnlpspec and $j2seVersion. Where do I set these variables? As it is now, the values being used are not reflecting project settings and I'm wondering if they are somehow hard coded?

**$jnlpspec**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="$encoding"?>
<jnlp
    spec="$jnlpspec"
    codebase="$jnlpCodebase"
    href="$outputFile">
```

**$j2seVersion**

```
<resources>
  <j2se version="$j2seVersion"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this one out myself. I needed to add these variables to the  tag, and the plugin configuration on pom.xml would thus look as below:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jnlp</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <codebase>[URL]</codebase>
                    <libPath>lib</libPath>
                    <unsignAlreadySignedJars>true</unsignAlreadySignedJars>
                    <jnlp>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        <spec>7.0</spec>
                        <j2seVersion>1.7</j2seVersion>
                        <inputTemplateResourcePath> ${project.basedir}/src/main/jnlp</inputTemplateResourcePath>
                        <inputTemplate>default-jnlp-template.vm</inputTemplate>
                        <offlineAllowed>false</offlineAllowed>
                    </jnlp>
                    <sign>
                        <keystore>${project.basedir}/keystore</keystore>
                        <keypass>password</keypass>
                        <storepass>password</storepass>
                        <alias>[ALIAS]</alias>
                        <dnameCn>[COMMON NAME]</dnameCn>
                        <dnameOu>[ORG. UNIT]</dnameOu>
                        <dnameO>[COMPANY]</dnameO>
                        <dnameL>[CITY]</dnameL>
                        <dnameSt>[STATE]</dnameSt>
                        <dnameC>[COUNTRY]</dnameC>
                        <verify>true</verify>
                        <keystoreConfig>
                            <delete>true</delete>
                            <gen>true</gen>
                        </keystoreConfig>
                    </sign>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```